# strange behavior for save action

Tags: grails

i have a strange behavior with domain saving , here is the domain:

```
class Ads {
String adTitle
String adDetails
String duration
Date dateCreated

static belongsTo = [user:Users]

static constraints = {
    category (nullable:false)
    adTitle (nullable:false, maxSize:100 )
    adDetails(nullable:false, maxSize:500 )
    duration (inList:["7 days", "14 days", "30 days"],nullable:true)
}

static mapping ={ duration (sqlType:"datetime") }
}
```

here is the **save action** in the controller:

```
    @Transactional
def save(Ads adsInstance) {
    if (adsInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (adsInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond adsInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }
    adsInstance.user=Users.get(springSecurityService.currentUserId)

    def adCreationDate = new Date()

    switch (adsInstance.duration) {//here i'm just modifying the duration 
        case "7 days":
            adsInstance.duration=adCreationDate+7

            break
        case "14 days":
            adsInstance.duration=adCreationDate+14

            break
        case "30 days":
            adsInstance.duration=adCreationDate+30

            break
        default:
            adsInstance.duration=adCreationDate+7

    }
    adsInstance.save flush:true
    if (adsInstance.isAttached()) //here the return is always not saved
    {
        println "Saved"
    }
    else
    {
        println " not Saved"
    }
    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [
                message(code: 'ads.label', default: 'Ads'),
                adsInstance.id
            ])
            //  redirect adsInstance
            redirect action:'show' ,id:adsInstance.id
        }
        '*' { respond adsInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

in the **adsInstance.isAttached()** i always getting **Not saved** although **adsInstance.save flush:true** is called before it , am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two things:

- After modifying the duration field, you are not validating the object again.
- You would have identified the issue yourself if you had added `failOnError: true` with save method.

You have added a constraint on `duration` field that it can contain values `["7 days", "14 days", "30 days"]` only. But inside switch block you are assigning it date type values which won't pass the validation. Secondly, according to the validation, the sql type for `duration` field should not be `datetime`. You should either create a custom validatior or use a transient field.

Comment: Ok i got it , but how i do that the user can choose from a list " 7,14,30 days" and i save his choice as a date in the DB?

Comment: add `["7 days", "14 days", "30 days"]` constraint on a transient field and then formulate value for `duration` field from the transient field value.

Comment: so how i could skip the validation on this field?

Comment: Remove the constraint from duration field and add it to new transient field. Change data type of duration field from String to Date.

Comment: i found a way to skip the validation but this will skip the validation for all fields , `save(validate:false)`

Comment: Why are you trying to skip the validation. Just add your constraints where they should be.